# LDAP backed Samba File Sharing - What is really required?

Tags: linux, networking, samba, freenas, ldap

I'm administrating a small network infrastructure consisting of a couple of Linux machines used for development and several web services. User management is done using a LDAP database which works very nicely. The clients to access this network are self-administered by their users and hence are not connected to the LDAP.

Recently the wish arouse to share user homes over all Linux machines and to be also able to access those home directories directly from the clients (which are a mixture of Apple and Windows machines). So in the test network I setup a FreeNAS box and integration into the LDAP as well as sharing home directories across several Linux machines has not been an issue. For accessing the homes from the clients, Samba was chosen as protocol since it is spoken by all machines.

That is kinda where things went ugly. While Samba on FreeNAS with local user management is very easy, apparently using LDAP requires a lot of schema changes to the database. Tutorials speak about setting up Windows Domain Controllers and managing clients which is all things I feel I don't really need. I just want users to access their homes on the NAS via Samba with credentials coming from LDAP instead of the local system user database.

So does anyone know what is really required in the LDAP database to achieve this goal? I gladly appreciate the help.